# gtest: EXPECT_ eventually

Tags: c++, googletest

I am testing code that by its nature produces results asynchronously. I don't have the ability to inject fine-grained instrumentation to control the flow. I would like to await for results before running assertions.

Right now I need to do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (!check_if_satisfied()) {
    sleep(1);
  }
}

EXPECT_TRUE(check_if_satisfied());
```

I would like to somehow have a helper method:

```
eventually(10 /* seconds */, [&]() {
  EXPECT_TRUE(check_if_satisfied());
});
```

I tried implementing and have a listener to intercept exception

```
  testing::TestEventListeners& listeners =
      testing::UnitTest::GetInstance()->listeners();
  auto printer = listeners.Release(listeners.default_result_printer());
  auto catchListener = new CatchingListener();
  listeners.Append(catchingListener);
  bool success = false
  while (true) {
    try {
      count++;
      fn();
      if (!Test::HasFailure()) {
        success = true;
      }
    } catch (...) {
    }
    if (success) {
      return;
    }
    sleep(1);
    if (count > 10) {
      break;
    }
  }
  listeners.Remove(catchingListener);
  fn()
...
```

but the problem is that the HasFailure remains and I don't see a public Clear method (also - I wouldn't like to clear it if there are other failures already).

(I am aware that above code isn't memory safe, it's only a demonstration)

Are there some ways for me to resolve this?